# CosmosDb - Insert a lot of data

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I developped an azure webjob used to insert a lot of data in a MongoDb CosmosDb databases.

Here is the following code from my repository used to insert data in the cosmosDb database :

```
public async Task<bool> InsertZonierDataAsync(List<Zonier> zonierList)
{
    if (zonierList == null || !zonierList.Any())
    {
        throw new ZonierListNullOrEmptyException();
    }

    try
    {
        await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            await _collection.InsertManyAsync(zonierList);
        });
        return true;
    }
    catch (MongoBulkWriteException ex)
    {
        throw new DataBaseWritingException(ex.Message, ExceptionCodeConstants.DataBaseWritingExceptionCode);
    }
}
```

In order to insert the data quickly, I update my RU/sec to 10K during the time my job is running.
There is something like 2 billion raw in the `zonierList` who needs to be inserted.

Unfortunatelly it takes a lot of time to insert the data throught the webjob (more than two hours). And when I check directly in CosmosDb the throughput, it is not blocked at 10K :

[image]

What have I done wrong and why is it taking so much time ? Can I change something throught configuration or should I change my way to insert data ?

Comment: What is `_collection`?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [bulk executor .NET library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net)?

Comment: The bulk executor library is currently only for SQL and Gremlin API. However, if this is more of a migration topic, look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview

Comment: It looks like the BulkImport is working with MongoDb databases. Link : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have provisioned 10k RUs for your container, Cosmos DB will split that amount equally across all of the physical partitions that make up that container. If all the documents you are inserting have the same partition key value then they will all go into the same logical and in return physical partition. That means that if your collection has 4 physical partitions you would only be using 2.5k out of the 10k you provisioned. The numbers add up.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation, so this is the reason why I'm stuck at 2.5K. My shardkey is set to `_id`, value given and forced by the DBA of my company. So i'm guessing that every documents is inserted directly into one partition out of 4. What is you advice for my case ?

Comment: This is very odd because `_id` in Mongo should be an `ObjectId` which should be randomised so my theory isn't necessarily correct in that scenario. That's assuming that CosmosDB doesn't do anything fancy behind the scenes that can cause that.

Comment: I insert a lot of document and the `_id` is not sent in the json document. It's generated by mongo directly. And it's not complitely random because it is related to the timestamp. So to fix my issue, the easiest way is to increase 4 times more my RU/sec during the job execution ?! What other option do I have ? I took a lot at the `BulkImport` but it requires a heavy refactoring part (I only have the mongodb connexion string in my webapp..)

Comment: The problem is that if you just want to do this to import some stuff initially and then scale down you might not be able to do it. Since you have so many documents Cosmos will use all the RUs you give it to generate many physical partitions to fit the data. However if you have a highly provisioned number you might not be able to scale back down to a significantly lower one because Cosmos might have created too many physical partitions and there is a minimum RU number to each of them.